# What should we do with [data-encryption]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

This is rather strange since every *data-encryption* is *encryption*, but not according to related tags of [data-encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-encryption) (35 Q). Also it doesn't have a tag wiki and no features to discern it from [encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption) (that I found at least).

Options:

1. Should it be burninated?
2. Should it be a synonym of [encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption)? (Synonym was proposed; go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/encryption/synonyms) to vote on it)
3. Leave it alone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think “data encryption” is *sometimes* used in database contexts to mean that some columns are encrypted, but the schema and relations aren't. The tag [data-encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-encryption) seems to be sometimes used with that meaning, but mostly interchangeably with [encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption). There is no value in having a separate tag name, and its existence is harmful because it dilutes searches.

Either retagging all the [data-encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-encryption) questions to [encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption), or merging the tag [data-encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-encryption) into [encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption), would be acceptable.

Comment: Haney ♦ [merged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278563/what-happens-to-a-tag-synonym-if-it-gets-burninated) it.