# What happens to a tag synonym if it gets "burninated"?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process

I organized some votes to put [data-encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-encryption) as a synonym of [encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption). It only has 36 questions.

Would the synonym actually vanish if all of the questions of [data-encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-encryption) would actually be retagged as [encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption)?

Should I request a merge by a moderator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can request a merge. Basically if a tag has 0 questions associated to it, it will be automatically burninated after a period of time. So, the ways to destroy a tag are:

1. Manually re-tag all things under the tag to the desired tag and then wait for the automated burnination of the tag which now has 0 questions.
2. Ask a mod for a merge which is a near-instant re-tag and burnination. The mod will do it *only if* it's a clear cut case (AKA the tag should *obviously* not exist).
3. Make the tag a synonym, in which case there will be no burnination.

Comment: Thanks! So there is no way around involving a moderator when a tag shouldn't exist on its own, but only as a transparent synonym. Is there a reason why not all tag synonyms are merged into their parent tag every day?

Comment: The community can create tag synonyms. Go to the tag page, click synonyms, and then follow the instructions. Example: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/support/synonyms

Comment: Yes, I know that, but when the synonym is approved the old questions still retain their synonym tag which is bad for searches.

Comment: Interesting point. Maybe search should be aware of tag synonyms (I'm working on improving search right now).