# Triggers synonym intermittently broken

Tags: bug, tags, search, tag-synonym-process, tag-search

For a long time, I've been using this link as a bookmark to new questions with any tag starting with `sql-server`:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server*

Recently, a whole bunch of unrelated questions have been popping up in those search results. For example, these two recent questions have nothing to do with SQL Server, and do not currently nor have they ever included any tag beginning with `sql-server`:

- [Rules and Triggers on Materialized Views in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757601/rules-and-triggers-on-materialized-views-in-postgresql)
- [Denormalization - maintaining redundancy by using triggers in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757199/denormalization-maintaining-redundancy-by-using-triggers-in-oracle)

Here's proof for the down-voters who aren't seeing what I'm seeing:

> [image]

What they do have in common is the tag [triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triggers). I looked at the [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/triggers/synonyms) recently and discovered that one of the synonyms was [sql-server-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-triggers) (a change made, I believe, by marc_s in November). BoltClock seems to have fixed this in part - [sql-server-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-triggers) is now reverted to an independent, unrelated tag. I don't know if that's the desired behavior in general, but it did seem to remove this SQL Server association with *all* trigger-related questions.

Except that it hasn't.

In fact Tim has confirmed that this isn't just happening with the wildcard search, but also if you search for just [sql-server-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-triggers). This is clearly 80% wrong:

> [image]

Can we please figure out why [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server*) and [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-triggers) *sometimes* yield all questions tagged with [triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triggers), regardless of platform? And more importantly, fix it?

Comment: lol, search borken in a new and different way.

Comment: Repro'ed, sporadically.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. I am not seeing it every time either, but often enough for it to be annoying. I suspect the change that Bolt made to the tag synonym hasn't been propagated everywhere?

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to guess one search or tag engine node isn't aware of the synonym removal, and what results you get depends on which one handles the work.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't aware this would break your searches. It just seemed unnecessary and unwanted to have `sql-server-triggers` - it seems to me just `triggers` would be plenty enough in those cases....

Comment: @marc_s Oh I agree, I don't think `sql-server-triggers` should be a tag at all. But making them synonyms seems like the wrong approach because of what it does to search...

Comment: @AaronBertrand: what other (better) approach is there?

Comment: @marc_s if the tag shouldn't exist (and I don't think it should), it can be deleted, blacklisted, etc. If the majority of people think it *should* exist (and I can see the argument for that too), then it should be left alone (and questions tagged `triggers` and `sql-server` retagged). [This also shouldn't be a tag IMHO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-group-concat), but I'm not going to debate any of that here - just want my searches to work consistently again.

Comment: This is probably related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278563/what-happens-to-a-tag-synonym-if-it-gets-burninated#comment125215_278568

Comment: wat... norepro.

Comment: @nicael As has been explained multiple times, the issue is intermittent (definition: doesn't happen every time). Do you think the screen shots are doctored, or Tim is colluding with me to invent an issue that doesn't exist?

Comment: No :) Ok, *now* complete norepro.

Comment: @nicael Ok, I'm happy for you. I would still like to see a fix, though (which may just mean waiting for all the nodes to catch up - but confirmation would be nice).